# Yarn workspaces and GCloud build

Tags: node.js, docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run, yarn-workspaces

I've created a monorepo with nodejs + typescript to publish a rest endpoint using yarn workspaces. This server will run on Google Cloud Run and use Google Container Registry.

The structure is the following

```
my-project /
   |
    -> common/
       package.json
   |
    -> server/
        -> src
        Dockerfile
        package.json
   |
    -> client/
       (react client that consume what server produce)
```

Common is a "shared" folder across projects in order to have a single package for types. I used the naming convention `@my-project/common` as the name of the common package to avoid collisions.

Then, I reference inside my server's code the common package:

in server's package json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@my-project/common": "1.0.0",
    ...
}
```

then in the actual code

```js
import { MyType } from '@my-project/common/type'
```

If it is any worth, here's also the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY ./dist ./
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

The build chain is

- cd to server's folder
- call build script with `yarn` that created the `dist/` folder with the compiled code
- exec `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-gcp-project-12345/my-gcp-project`to push to GCR

Here's the problem: Cloud Build can't find the common package:
`An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@my-project%2fcommon: Not found".`

Is it possible to find a solution to this, without pushing the common package to a private registry?

Comment: I rather use `npm` so maybe I do not understand something: What do you mean by "call build script with `yarn` that created the `dist/` folder with the compiled code"? At least by default `yarn` is not creating any such directory... I don't think as well that js is creating "compiled" code....

Comment: Hey @vitooh thank you. In my package.json, "yarn build" calls TSC to transpile Typescript to JS so this is where my "compiled" code comes out. Sorry for the confusion created with compiled code

Comment: Hey @valerio, have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @kuzzmi no, and I don't follow up this anymore. The answer from Miguel Coxo helped, but in the end I've moved to a different project logic.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar case but with cloud functions maybe it can help you.

Before deploying the functions we have to run a `yarn pack` on our `@company/common` lib and then `yarn add file:packName.tgz` to the functions.

In our case since we are still using package-lock.json on the deploy side we then have to run `npm i --package-lock-only` just to update the integrity field on the `package-lock.json`

After deployment we have to revert the `package.json` back to our version of the lib.

Quite a "hack" but works.